# Is it possible to set a more generic process affinity (automatically)?

Tags: cpu, windows-server-2003, multi-core, affinity

I know with `start /affinity X` where X is a hex-number bit-masking the CPUs to be used a process can be started to use certain CPUs only. However, is there a possibility to state something like "start this process using 50% of the available cores, pick them on your own, but don't use CPU3"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That functionality is not exposed via command-line (nor Windows API supports it directly).

It should be relatively straight forward to implement is in specific code but that would most definitely require custom program. I am not aware that there is program supporting such rich functionality.

Comment: ...especially if I add "and it should be free and not require admin rights" :p